# how to write a oracle sql query order by two columns

Tags: oracle

I have a table include two columns, year and month, I want get a unique result that order by year and month.

example:

```
y      m
2013   12 
2012   1
2013   4
2012   3
```

I want get

```
y      m
2013  12
```

How to write the SQL query. thanks.

Comment: What does your existing query look like?  And do you really want to **order** the data, or just extract the row with the latest date?

Comment: please take the time to read the SQL definition of 'ORDER BY', your example does not support the mention of that sytax. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where y = 2013 and m = 12;
```

Do you want this ?

Comment: thanks , but this is not what i want . i've got the answer . like this : select * from (
select * from table order by year desc,month desc
)
where rownum=1